# Site-To-Site VPN with Quagga

Tags: site-to-site-vpn, quagga

Can Quagga broadcast a statically configured routes to all the computers in that network.

Say for example I have network 10.0.1.0/16. In one of the PC in this network I am running Quaaga server and have configured a route there. Can this route be broadcasted to all the elements in this network?

I was trying to find some online help. But, was not successful.

I need this for the following scenario of mine -

I am using SoftEther VPN Server to make a site to site VPN say between 10.0.10/16 and 30.0.1.0/16 and now the site to site VPN is established, I want to install a route on all the elements in that 10.0.1.0/16 to send the traffic to 30.0.1.0 through this VPN server.

Can anyone please help me out with the Quagga configuration to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use Quagga to redistribute your static routes.
First we will need to define a dynamic routing protocol like RIP, OSPF or BGP, etc which runs on Quagga.

You will need to use Quagga to create a static route via zebra.conf; IF, for example you use RIP (for the dynamic routing protocol), you will configure ripd.conf to redistribute all your existing routes to the rest of your network, you will use something like:
redistribute connected
redistribute static

you can do some research for some examples for RIPD on QUAGGA.

Comment: If you're going to post an answer, great. But don't spam us all with links to your business. If you want to promote your business, SE will be glad to take your money for placement on one of their advertisement slots.

Comment: My apology, I do not intend to include any spams here. This is my first time to post here. Thanks for the edit.